# How to determine if CI script is running on GitHub server

Tags: bash, ubuntu, github, continuous-integration

I have a build script that runs whenever I push something to a repository. However I also want to run the script locally because I dont want to push a commit that will fail on server. My problem is that some programs differ on my local testing environment and the server. How could I determine if the script is running on the server? The best solution would be if the server had some env variable i could check. A bad solution would be to add some env to my local computer because that is not scalable across team members.

For my specific case:
I want to compile my source on GH but to do that I need to install some dependencies. On GH I my commands should start with `sudo` however when using [local tesing](https://github.com/nektos/act) I need to install sudo before using it (or just drop it).

Answer (score 2):

you can check if your script is ran in GH (or other CI) environment via `CI` environment variable. And if value is not empty you need add `sudo` to your command

```
SUDO=''
if [[ ! -z "$CI" ]]; then
    SUDO='sudo'
fi
$SUDO a_command
```

Comment: When using `set -o nounset` (aka `set -u`) this causes the script to crash with `CI: unbound variable`, do you have an alternative to check if CI is not set / not true ?